# How can I use WPF's drawing namespace in a Windows Store app?

Tags: wpf, windows-store-apps

Probably a pointless question, but is there anyway I can use WPF's

> xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"

(for drawing shapes etc.) namespace in a Windows Store app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it isn't WPFs namespace, but .Net 4's namespace. And the .Net 4.5 framework for Windows store apps doesn't support those same libraries. Its basically a different run time environment.

Having said that, there must be someway to draw shapes, try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.aspx

Comment: true, but i wanted stuff like callouts, stars etc.